# how to get last index and value from map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I had following sorted map and I need to get last index and value from this map. please help me to find.

`var sort_bort_card_value=new Map([...bot_card_value.entries()].sort());`

thanks in advance...

Comment: You can not directly access the Map object with index. you will have to iterate over them.  or `myMap.get(key)`

Comment: See here: https://gist.github.com/tizmagik/19ba6516064a046a37aff57c7c65c9cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either iterate it and take the last element

```
for(var last of sort_bort_card_value) {}
console.log(last)
```

Or convert it to an array so we can use `.shift`

```
Array.from(sort_bort_card_value).shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would help

```js
let someMap = new Map();
someMap.set("key1", "value1");
someMap.set("key2", "value2");
someMap.set("key3", "value3");

const getLastItemInMap = (map) => Array.from(map)[map.size - 1];
const getLastKeyInMap = (map) => Array.from(map)[map.size - 1][0];
const getLastValueInMap = (map) => Array.from(map)[map.size - 1][1];

console.log(getLastItemInMap(someMap));
console.log(getLastKeyInMap(someMap));
console.log(getLastValueInMap(someMap));
```